# Filter data frame columns based on list values

Tags: r, list, dataframe, filter

I have a data frame as such:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c(1,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
       var2 = c(11,11,33,44,55,66,77,88,99),
       var3 = c(111,111,333,444,555,666,777,888,999),
       var4 = c(1111,1111,3333,4444,5555,6666,7777,8888,9999))
> df
  var1 var2 var3 var4
1    1   11  111 1111
2    1   11  111 1111
3    3   33  333 3333
4    4   44  444 4444
5    5   55  555 5555
6    6   66  666 6666
7    7   77  777 7777
8    8   88  888 8888
9    9   99  999 9999
```

I would like to filter for specific rows based on multiple column values stored in a list.

For example:

```
my_list <- list(var1 = 1,
     var2 = 11,
     var3 = 111)
filtered_df <- df %>% filter(var1 == my_list$var1[[1]],
              var2 == my_list$var2[[1]],
              var3 == my_list$var3[[1]])
> filtered_df
  var1 var2 var3 var4
1    1   11  111 1111
2    1   11  111 1111
```

Instead of including every variable within `filter`, can I select the elements within my list and filter the data frame using the names of my list?

Comment: Ah, if all questions were as well-structured and helper-friendly as this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you suggest is very similar to the natural way of things in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[my_list, on = .(var1, var2, var3)]

   var1 var2 var3 var4
1:    1   11  111 1111
2:    1   11  111 1111
```

If you specify your keys first, the filtering is more concise:

```
setkey(df, var1, var2, var3)
df[my_list]
```

A *base R* alternative:

```
df[rowSums(df[1:3] == my_list) == 3L, ]
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution is this:

First you paste the values in your list together collapsing them by the alternation marker `|`:

```
my_list_1 <- paste0(unlist(my_list), collapse = "|")
my_list_1
[1] "1|11|111"
```

Then, using this alternation string `my_list_1` as well as pasting the rows of your dataframe together using `apply`, you subset your dataframe on those rows that match `my_list_1`:

```
df[which(grepl(my_list_1, apply(df, 1, paste0, collapse = " "))),]
  var1 var2 var3 var4
1    1   11  111 1111
2    1   11  111 1111
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution involving `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `purrr` could be:

```
map_dfr(.x = imap(my_list, setNames), 
        ~ enframe(.x) %>%
         inner_join(df %>%
                     rowid_to_column() %>%
                     pivot_longer(-rowid))) %>%
 group_by(rowid) %>%
 filter(n() == length(my_list)) %>%
 slice(1) %>%
 inner_join(df %>%
             rowid_to_column(), by = c("rowid" = "rowid")) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(starts_with("var"))

   var1  var2  var3  var4
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    11   111  1111
2     1    11   111  1111
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It's very educational but somewhat complex.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative using `rlang::parse_expr()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

df %>%
  filter(!!parse_expr(paste(names(my_list), my_list, sep = "==", collapse = "&")))

  var1 var2 var3 var4
1    1   11  111 1111
2    1   11  111 1111
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just a quick follow up question. How can I force parse_expr to include special characters such as "_". For example, if the first row in my df is now: `var1 = "1_1", var2 = 11, var3 = 111, var4 = 1111` and `my_list = list(var1 = "1_1", var 2 = 11, var3 = 111)`.